# Create Page Header and Footer for a CPL report

Tags: activereports, componentone

I am unable to spot documentation on adding a page header and/or page footer to a Continuous Page Layout report. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add PageHeader/PageFooter to a CPL report, you can follow these steps.

1. Open the CPL report in Design View inside Visual Studio.
2. Go to the Report menu in Visual Studio.
3. At the bottom of the drop down, you will see options to add PageHeader and PageFooter.
4. Select them as required.